# How to show that $\ell^p(w)$ space is separable?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification

Let $1\le p <\infty$ and $w_n> 0$ for $n=1,2,\dots$. We define the space
$$
\ell^p(w)=\{\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}: \|x\|_{p,w}<\infty\}
$$
where $\|x\|^p_{p,w}=\sum_{k\ge 1} |x_k|^p w_k$. Now, I try to show that $\ell^p(w)$ is separable.

My proof is as follows. I choose the countable set of $\ell^p(w)$ by
$$
A=\{(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n, 0,0,\dots): x_i \in \mathbb{Q}, 1\le i\le n\}
$$
Then $A$ is a countable subset of $\ell^p(w)$.

For every $\epsilon>0$, I choose $y\in \ell^p(w)$. Since $\|y\|_{p,w}<\infty$, then there exists $N>0$ so that $n>N$
$$
\sum_{I=N+1}^{\infty} |y_i|^pw_i<\frac{\epsilon^p}{2}
$$

Also, for all $1\le i\le N$, where exists $x_i\in \mathbb{Q}$ so that
$$
|y_i-x_i|w_i^{1/p}\le \frac{\epsilon}{2^{(i+1)/p}}
$$

Hence,
$$
\|y-x\|^p_{p,w}=\sum_{I=1}^{N}|y_i-x_i|^pw_i+\sum_{I\ge N+1}|y_i|^pw_i\le \sum_{i=1}^N\frac{\epsilon^p}{2^{i+1}}+\frac{\epsilon^p}{2}\le \epsilon^p
$$

Hence, we found a countable dense set $A$ in $\ell^p(w)$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Fix it. Thank you!

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes! Thank you. Fix it.